# Laptop external Speaker sometimes Mono

Tags: windows-10, audio, speakers

I have stereo speaker + subwoofer connected to my win10 laptop via AUX cable. Sometimes, while watching videos, the speaker seem to break to mono and only the left speaker works. First I thought the problems are the (a bit older) speaker, but then I realized, when I reinsert the AUX cable on my laptop, it works again for some times. That's why I think the problem isn't by the speaker. What do you think is the problem? Tell me if you need more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Prime causes - cheap sockets & dirty contacts.

1. Cheapest solution - switch everything off & plug/unplug the plug in/out of the socket 50 times [gently].
2. Slightly better solution - do the same, but spray the sockets with contact cleaner first.
3. Prime solution - a new socket, but that requires you already own the necessary soldering equipment & ability to take the unit apart.

If you get as far as 3 without existing equipment, it's probably cheaper to buy new speakers.

In all instances, make sure everything is switched off before you do it. If you use contact cleaner, allow an extra half hour to be sure it's fully evaporated before powering up again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I don't have a contact cleaner so I tried the cheap version. I have to test it now so I can be sure that the problem is fixed for now. :)

Comment: So I tried it and it worked longer than usual but now, after an hour, it occured again :( I sure appreciate your answer because it really seems to be the contact creating this failure! But is there any way (without contact cleaner) to fix it? Because I don't want to buy something which doesnt even guarantee that it will work and I won't need for anything else

Comment: A better socket - the existing one may be sprained. ¼ the price of a can of contact cleaner, but requires you to already own a soldering iron.

Comment: Okay, but it's hard work to replace that in my laptop. I just found out that I own a Headset with a USB adapter which has an AUX port on it. I just tried it and it seems to work! But the problem still occurs sometimes..